# How might the characters â€‹ can appear in the served HTML but not in my source code?

Tags: javascript

My source code is:

```
//this is a helper function know as an Immediately Invoked Function Expression - 
//use this to fix a closure within a loop
    function iife(j){
        return function () {
            return  j;​
        } ();
    }
```

But when this is served to the browser, I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` pointing to

```
    function iife(j){
        return function () {
            return  j;â€‹
        } ();
    }
```

I'm using a Node.js server which does no pre-processing on the HTML. It's just straightforward serving. I've been using this server for months and have had no unexpected results.

As an additional interesting detail, while there seem to be no spaces after the code in question in my source, my IDE, Aptana Studio, is having trouble highlighting text now. If I delete that code, or even copy and re-paste it, the highlighting goes back to normal for a while. I've even tried re-typing that line from scratch but the problem persists.

**Where might be the cause of these â€‹ characters?**

Comment: Getting `â` usually means you've got a unicode character in a non-unicode context - e.g. a character set mismatch.

Comment: You've "\u200b\u200b"  at the end of the line (two zero-width spaces). Just remove the line and re-write it.

Comment: @Teemu I set my code editor to only use UTF-8, and re-typed that line and it still didn't work, but your comment helped me because the only way to get rid of something as wild as a zer-width space is to delete content you can't see or select, so I had to delete the content starting from the next line, through the semi colon on the problematic line. You should mention this in an answer.

Comment: @JonathanTodd That might be an editor dependent issue, but as I said:  "_remove the line_", i.e. including the new-line character. That usually can be done by selecting the actual line and dragging the cursor to the beginning of the next line and hitting DEL ... For the future, if your editor doesn't show all characters, use [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2yoty7yk/), it shows a red dot representing illegal characters. You can copy the dot(s), and paste it/them to a converter, (for example [here](https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter)) to see, what you actually have.

Answer (score 3):

This is a character encoding issue.  The editor displaying your source code can handle it just fine, but the JavaScript interpreter cannot.

Make sure your editor is configured for UTF-8 encoding.

These types of encoding issues often arise when "fancy" versions of punctuation marks like slanted quotes are used instead of the standard ones.

Comment: Important note, since @Teemu explained there was `\u200b\u200b` after my semicolon (two zero-width spaces), even after setting my text editor to use UTF-8 only, the zero-width spaces remained (invisible), and I couldn't select them, so the problem persisted. The solution I discovered thanks to that knowledge was to delete the line starting from the *next line* and retype that line and line break.

Comment: Any idea how those characters got in there?